# Can't I create milions of Bitcoin addresses and wait if someone will have same one?

Tags: address

If Bitcoin addresses can be generated offline, then the Bitcoin network doesn't check for duplicate addresses while generating a new one. Can't I just make a script and generate milions of Bitcoin addresses and then make a profit when someone will have one of those addresses and sends bitcoins there?

How does the Bitcoin network prevent this?

Comment: It is practically impossible. Check out some great answers here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/is-each-bitcoin-address-unique

Answer (score 2):

While this is theoretically possible, it is [practically impossible](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Weaknesses#Generating_tons_of_addresses).

> Keys are 256 bit in length and are hashed in a 160 bit address.(2^160th power) Divide it by the world population and you have about 215,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 addresses per capita.(2.15 x 10^38

Answer (score 1):

Probability prevents this from happening as the bitcoin address space is 2^160 or

```
1,461,501,600,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 (apx)
```

[here is a picture to put it into perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWwJq.png). Ok so now you are thinking well it is quick to generate them so I will just make more. Looking at this thread [How to pre-generate 100M bitcoin addresses?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/how-to-pre-generate-100m-bitcoin-addresses) you can generate 770k addresses in 15 minutes so lets do the math. that is

```
54,168,210,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 (apx)
```

years to generate all the bitcoin addresses. get cracking.