# Vanitygen: How ot store all generated addresses?

Tags: vanity-address, vanitygen

i want to know it is possible to store all generated addresses into file (or DB). 
How it can be? 
For example i need to generate 1,000,000,000 addresses, with vanitygen speed about 50M per second.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/how-to-pre-generate-100m-bitcoin-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./vanitygen -k 1 -o output.txt
```

will generate addressses until you stop it, and will save the addresses to `output.txt`. It won't be formatted, so it's a better idea to use [Vanitygen Plus](https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus)'s [`-z` option](https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus/blob/c0f2cc31a90042daa91d0ef317f0f467fcecf45d/vanitygen.c#L355), which formats the output as CSV.

Comment: it is fatest way? Dont it be slowed by writing 1 string in file each time?
I know what operations like write in file are very slow.