# New Numbers: How many Bitcoin addresses are/have been carrying a balance?

Tags: pybitcointools

Same question as this: [How many Bitcoin addresses are/have been carrying a balance?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/how-many-bitcoin-addresses-are-have-been-carrying-a-balance)

However the answer there is from 2012. Anybody have the new numbers for reference?

Comment: The description is not very clear, but this chart may be related to what you're looking for: https://blockchain.info/de/charts/n-unique-addresses?timespan=all&daysAverageString=7

Answer (score 2):

Though, I don't have the exact number, an approximate number can be inferred from the number of unspent transaction output set or [UTXO](https://blockchain.info/charts/utxo-count?timespan=all).

Each address with non zero balance will have an entry in UTXO. These days wallet create new address for each payment, so commonly addresses have one txout. However, most people reuse addresses and are used for donation, go through mixers etc and they end up with multiple UTXO.

Taking an approximate number of 2 UTXO per address.  This factor approximately matches with the number of addresses calculated in [2012](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/how-many-bitcoin-addresses-are-have-been-carrying-a-balance) and the UTXO values for 2012 in [the blockchain.info chart](https://blockchain.info/charts/utxo-count?timespan=all)

For 2017, looking up from [blockchain.info UTXO chart](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/how-many-bitcoin-addresses-are-have-been-carrying-a-balance) gives

47.3 million /2  ~ 23.6 million address